# How return custom XML response in soapServer response?

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

I am setting up a SOAP webservice which takes XML input and has to return custom XML output.
All this is defined in a WSDL. I apply soapServer for this (until someone says it has bugs preventing me from achieving my goal :-)).

I haven't been able yet to return custom XML: I get some result which seems to be based on teh WSDL, with a standard root element name equal to the input XML one plus "Response".
Actually that surprises me too so as a side question I wonder why that is and whether it can be influenced. Of course it is a nice thing that the WSDL definitions are used somehow when responses are created, but as I said, I don't know how to get custom XML in the response.

I got as far as this:

WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://pse/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    name="PSE"
    targetNamespace="http://pse/">
    <types>
        <xs:schema>
            <xs:import namespace="http://pse/" schemaLocation="PSE.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="MI102Req">
        <part name="cdhead" type="tns:cdhead_T"/>
        <part name="instr" type="tns:instr_T"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Res">
        <part name="cdhead" type="tns:cdhead_T"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MIPortType">
        <operation name="mi102">
            <input message="tns:MI102Req"/>
            <output message="tns:Res"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MIBinding" type="tns:MIPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="mi102">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.testURL/test_soap.php#mi102"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://pse/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://pse/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="PSE">
        <port name="MIPortType" binding="tns:MIBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.testURL/test_soap.php"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Input XML

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <mi102 xmlns="http://pse">
            <cdhead version="13"/>
            <instr/>
        </mi102>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

current php

```
<?php
    class PSE {
        function mi102 ($stdClassInput) {
            $inp = file_get_contents ('php://input');
            $xml = simplexml_load_string ($inp); // Envelope
            $ch = $xml -> children ();
            $elt1 = $ch [0]; // Body
            $ch = $elt1 -> children ();
            $elt2 = $ch [0]; //mi102

            $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
            $xslt -> registerPHPFunctions();
            $xslt -> importStylesheet ( DOMDocument::load ('test.xslt') );
            $dom = $xslt -> transformToDoc (DOMDocument::loadXML ($elt2 -> asXML()));

            $result = new SoapVar ($dom -> saveXML(), XSD_ANYXML);  
            return ($result);
        }
    }

    ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    $server = new SoapServer ("test.wsdl");
    $server -> setClass ('PSE');
    $server -> setObject (new PSE());
    $server -> handle();
?>
```

XSLT used above is just one changing an attribute - and temp change the root name to the one returned by the server always (just in case :-))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pse="http://pse">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pse:mi102">
        <mi102Response>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </mi102Response>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pse:cdhead">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@version">
        <xsl:attribute name="version">14</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expect the return XML to be something like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://pse/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:mi102Response>
            <cdhead version="14"/>
        </ns1:mi102Response>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But instead it is

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://pse/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:mi102Response/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Debugging $dom contents in above php shows exactly the XML I try to return (wrapped in SOAP Envelope/Body, of course, just like the input one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mi102Response xmlns:pse="http://pse">
    <cdhead xmlns="http://pse" version="14"/>
</mi102Response>
```

Where do I go wrong?
How get custom XML into the returned http response content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Phew!

This took me several retries and googling until I discovered what is wrong.
I think it can be classified as a bug in `SoapVar`.

I discovered that while SoapVar is perfectly capable of parsing an XML string, it cannot do so if the string contains an XML declaration like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.
So when you have a `DOMDocument` or a `SimpleXMLElement`, you first have to strip off the declaration before parsing the string by SoapVar.

for a `DOMDocument` this can be done by applying `saveXML` with a parameter equal to a `DOMNode` variable constructed from the dom itself, choosing any node but usually this will be the root node of course.

In my server php, I added the following:

```
$nodes = $dom -> getElementsByTagName ('cdhead');
$node = $nodes -> item(0);

$result = new SoapVar ($dom -> saveXML($node), XSD_ANYXML);
```

And now my result is OK:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://pse/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:mi102Response>
        <cdhead version="14"/>
    </ns1:mi102Response>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As for the root name of the returned XML - I am sure I will find out a way to change that to whatever I want it to be (instead of the standard mi102Response generated by SoapVar)!!